# SAS count and summarize if conditions on variables are true

Tags: sas

I have a data set with 3 columns: Name, System, UserID. I want to count how many times an individual appears in the report, but not count them if they're different people with the same name. Distinction is made by the UserID field and only within a single system. If a single name has multiple lines with the same system and different User ID, then all the observations with that name would be marked for review. For this data set, I would want to see the output below.

```
Name       System   UserID
John Doe   Sys1     [blank]
John Doe   Sys1     AB1234
John Doe   Sys2     AB2345
Jane Doe   Sys1     AA2345
Jane Doe   Sys1     AA23456
Jane Doe   Sys2     AA2345
Joe Smith  Sys1     JS963
Joe Smith  Sys2     JS741


Name       Count  System                      Follow-up
John Doe   1      Sys1 -                      Yes
John Doe   1      Sys1 - AB1234               Yes
John Doe   1      Sys2 - AB2345               Yes
Jane Doe   1      Sys1 - AA2345               Yes
Jane Doe   1      Sys1 - AA23456              Yes
Jane Doe   1      Sys2 - AA2345               Yes
Joe Smith  2      Sys1 - JS963, Sys2 - JS741  No
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code I have is below. It's currently just doing a count of names in general and don't know how to add the conditions.

```
PROC SQL;

     CREATE TABLE Sorted_Master_Original AS

     SELECT Name,
            COUNT(Name) AS Total,
            System,
            UserID,
            CATX(' - ',System,UserID) AS SystemID

     FROM Master_Original

     WHERE Name <> ""

     GROUP BY Name;

QUIT;

DATA TESTDATA.Final_Listing;

LENGTH SystemsAccessed $200.;

   DO UNTIL (last.Name);

   SET Sorted_Master_Original;

   BY Name NOTSORTED;

   SystemsAccessed=CATX(', ',SystemsAccessed,SystemID);

END;

DROP System SystemID;

RUN;
```

Comment: Please include anything you've attempted so far to solve this problem.

Comment: And why is Joe Smith combined, but John Doe from record 2/3 is not presented in a similar manner?

Comment: Updated the post to include the coding i have so far. Joe Smith is combined because his 2 observations are for different systems. John Doe has 2 observations with Sys1, but the User ID fields do not match and therefore those lines are tagged for follow up.

Comment: Additionally, if there is one instance where a name has multiple user IDs for the same system, then all of the observations with that name will need to be tagged for follow-up.

Comment: That doesn't explain the difference, they both have two systems (1/2) and different ID's in each system. Is it because JohnDoe has two IDs in System 1 that don't match?

Comment: Yes, it is because there are two IDs in Sys1 for John Doe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of determining a signal over a group, and then applying to each member in the group can be accomplished using two DOW loops in sequence.  The first is as you have coded with a `last.` loop test and the `set` and `by` within the loop, and the second will be for reiterating the group via a like sized loop over the group in separate SET buffer -- at which time the signal can be applied.

Data

```
data have;
length Name System UserID $20;
input Name & System & UserID; datalines;
John Doe   Sys1     .
John Doe   Sys1     AB1234
John Doe   Sys2     AB2345
Jane Doe   Sys1     AA2345
Jane Doe   Sys1     AA23456
Jane Doe   Sys2     AA2345
Joe Smith  Sys1     JS963
Joe Smith  Sys2     JS741
Bob Smith  Sys3     MS13
run;
```

Order for by group processing

```
proc sort data=have;
  by Name System UserId;
run;
```

DATA Step with sequential DOW loops

```
data want(keep=name count system_userid_list followup);
  * loop over name group;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name system userid;

    * tests of conditions within the group determine some signal;

    * check if there is more than one userid within a system within the name group;
    if not (first.system and last.system) then
      count = 1;
  end;

  if not count then count = _n_;

  length system_userid_list $200;
  followup = ifc(count=1 and _n_>1 ,'Yes','No');

  * followup 'signal' will be applied/available to each row of the group;

  * either output single row as followup, or concat to an aggregate list;
  * mixed output of singles and aggregates, good idea?;

  * reiterate over group in second SET buffer;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    item = catx(' - ',system,userid);
    if count > 1 then
      system_userid_list = catx(',',system_userid_list,item);
    else do;
      system_userid_list = item;
      output;
    end;
  end;

  if count > 1 then output;
run;
```